# MongoDB / Mongoose $pull (remove) Sub Document not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Smashing my head into the keyboard over this.

Simply need to remove subdocument. Example below only has one item in OnCommands but there could be a many items there. I have tried find, findbyid, updatebyId, pull, one things after another. Tried by _id of subdoc and by generic searchinMost simple run without doing anything no errors.

I would be so greatful if you can show me what I am doing wrong, it's the last part of my code that isn't work.

**Sample Data:**

```
> db.EntryPoints.find({_id: ObjectId("569e4fabf1e4464495ebf652")}).pretty()
{
        "__v" : 0,
        "_id" : ObjectId("569e4fabf1e4464495ebf652"),
        "name" : "bbbb",
        "offCommands" : [ ],
        "onCommands" : [
                {
                        "data" : "11111",
                        "operation" : "on",
                        "command" : "ISY-HTTPGet",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("569e4faff1e4464495ebf653")
                }
        ]
```

**Model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var onCommandsSchema = new Schema({
    command: String
    ,operation: String
    ,data: String
})

var offCommandsSchema = new Schema({
    command: String
    ,operation: String
    ,data: String
})

mongoose.model('onCommands', onCommandsSchema);
mongoose.model('offCommands', offCommandsSchema);

// create a schema
var EntryPointsSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
    ,onCommands: [onCommandsSchema]
    ,offCommands: [offCommandsSchema]
    ,description: String
}, { collection: 'EntryPoints' });
mongoose.model('EntryPoints', EntryPointsSchema);


var EntryPoints = mongoose.model('EntryPoints');

module.exports = EntryPoints;
```

**Node Post Code:**

```
router.post('/webservices/removeCommand', function (req, res) {
    var EntryPoints = require('../data_models/automate_entrypoints.js');

    EntryPoints.update(
        { _id: ObjectId(req.body._id) }
        , {
            $pull: {
                onCommands: { id_: req.body._id }
            }
        }
        , function (err, ouput) { console.log("data:", numAffected) }
    );  

});
```

Comment: Have you tried $unwind aggregation operation? https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/  $unwind will break the array into objects and you can access the objects dot(.) operator. In your case, once onCommands field is unwinded, you can access documents with onCommands.data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code won't work because of the query part of your update: you want to match on the embedded document's `_id`, not on the main document. So change it to

```
var EntryPoints = require('../data_models/automate_entrypoints.js');

EntryPoints.update(
    { "onCommands._id": req.body._id }, 
    {
        "$pull": {
            "onCommands": { "_id": req.body._id }
        }
    }, 
    function (err, numAffected) { console.log("data:", numAffected) }
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I still dont understand why that works. I did mistakenly put in my post here that I was using the parent doc _id but I was passing the subdoc's id. The key seemed to be using onCommands.id: subdocid.

Comment: Im, as well, not sure why to query for the subdocument and then again query for subdocument within $pull again?